# Tengo un problema al ingresar datos en un array de struct mediante una función - C/C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Creé un proyecto de *C++*, consta de dos archivos: un `main.cpp` y otro de `funciones.h`. Logré que compile pero se rompe y deja de funcionar al querer cargar ingresos en un array de `struct` mediante una función.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>

struct datos{
    int codigo;
    char dni[10];
    char apellido[50];
    char nombre [50];
    int edad;
    int tipo;
    int colesterol;
    float gbrojos;
    float gbblancos;
};
struct fecha{
    int anio;
    int mes;
    int dia;
};

#include "funciones.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    datos *ext[10];
    fecha *fch[10];

    while(true){
        int opcion;

        system("cls");

        cout << endl << "MENU PRINCIPAL" << endl;
        cout << endl << "1) EXTRACCIONES";
        cout << endl << "2) REPORTES";
        cout << endl << "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -";
        cout << endl << "0) SALIR DEL PROGRAMA" << endl;

        cin >> opcion;

        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                menuextracciones(*ext, *fch);
            break;
            case 2:
            break;
            case 0:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí está el código de `funciones.h`

```
#ifndef FUNCIONES_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCIONES_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void menuextracciones(datos *ext, fecha *fch){
    int opcionextr = 7, vecstate = 0, i;
    while(opcionextr != 0){
        system("cls");
        cout << endl << "MENU EXTRACCIONES" << endl;
        cout << endl << "1) CARGAR NUEVA EXTRACCION";
        cout << endl << "2) EDITAR EXTRACCION";
        cout << endl << "3) LISTAR TODAS LAS EXTRACCIONES";
        cout << endl << "4) LISTAR EXTRACCION POR CODIGO";
        cout << endl << "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -";
        cout << endl << "0) VOLVER AL MENU PRINCIPAL" << endl;
        cin >> opcionextr;

        switch(opcionextr){
            case 1:
                system ("cls");
                cout << "Ingrese un codigo: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].codigo;
                for(i=0;i<vecstate;i++){
                    if(ext[i].codigo == *ext[vecstate].codigo){
                        cout << endl << "Codigo en uso.";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cout << endl << "Ingrese dni del paciente: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].dni;
                cout << endl << "Ingrese apellido del paciente: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].apellido;
                cout << endl << "Ingrese nombre del paciente: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].nombre;
                cout << endl << "Ingrese edad del paciente: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].edad;
                cout << endl << "Ingrese tipo: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].tipo;
                cout << endl << "Ingrese nivel de colesterol: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].colesterol;
                cout << endl << "Ingrese nivel de globulos blancos: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].gbblancos;
                cout << endl << "Ingrese nivel de globulos rojos: " << endl;
                cin >> ext[vecstate].gbrojos;
                vecstate++;
            break;
            case 2:
            break;
            case 3:
            break;
            case 4:
            break;
            case 0:
            break;
        }
    }
}
#endif // FUNCIONES_H_INCLUDED
```

Logré que compile, pero al cargar datos en el vector, el programa deja de funcionar. Windows me avisa que el programa dejó de funcionar, y luego el programa termina. ¿Cómo podría depurarlo?

No está completo porque no pude probarlo. ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: "*se rompe y deja de funcionar al querer cargar ingresos*" ⬅️ ¿Podrías especificar cómo? ¿Da un error específico? ¿Deja de responder? ¿Qué sucede? ... Además, ¿hiciste algo para depurarlo o encontrar en qué línea se produce?

Comment: windows me avisa que el programa dejo de funcionar. y luego el programa termina. 
como podria depurarlo?

Comment: probe hacerlo de nuevo mas simplificado, pero sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: @Paulo prueba con mi sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia esto

```
if(ext[i].codigo == *ext[vecstate].codigo){
```

Por esto

```
if(ext[i].codigo == ext[vecstate].codigo){
```

en el archivo `funciones.h` ya que el * es innecesario ya que `ext` ya es el puntero a la data.

Comment: gracias! funciono o.o

Comment: @Paulo Si mi respuesto te ayudo marcala como correcta por favor

Comment: @Paulo ademas de ello mi compilador me aviso de la equivocación :V